# SharePoint workflow condition on multiple choice column

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, conditional-statements, designer, multiple-choice

I try to have a condition on a multiple choice column.
With single choice it is working easyly but I could not find a method
to do it with a multiple choice column.

For instance, the column named "Choices" has the possible values:  Car, Bike, Bus, Plane

So I want a condition to check for the values that were selected (in pseudocode)

IF Choices contains "Car" then ....

IF Choices contains "Bike" then ....

IF Choices contains "Bus" then ....

IF Choices contains "Plane" then ....

But in the designer when I tried to implement such a condition, im not able to write this structure.

Someone told me to convert the values from the multiple chpice column to a calculated column to work with it, but isnt there a more comfortable solution?

I already asked it in the the social TechNet with the described solution:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/41faa48a-85e9-4526-b416-05cf3eeb2e0b/sharepoint-designer-workflow-condition-on-multiple-choice-field?forum=sharepointcustomization

But I dont believe I am the only one who ever needed such a condition.

**UPDATE:** Since it appears to be the only solution I am copying the value of the multiple choice column as choice value to a workflow variable of type string. Then the string is set as value for a normal text column. Now I can have the condition

```
IF value of clolumn contains "Car" then....
```